Xubuntu does not detect Arch Linux
Good morning,
Today I was trying to install Xubuntu 22.04.4 LTS next to my main OS (Arch Linux), but in the installer it doesn't detect the Arch partition.
Anyone know how to solve it?

Providing details as to the file-system involved may help, as I have had cases where an installer does not detect what is there because of unusual file-systems being used.

ext4, i would to use half dish for arch and half disk for xubuntu

Possible duplicate of How to use manual partitioning during installation?

Nowhere near enough info. You must provide details of your drives, partitioning system, partition layout, firmware type, bootloader type, etc. for us to have anything to go on.
